# Unable to checkout repos from other project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm having hard time refactoring my current release pipeline into yaml pipeline. The pipeline uses current repo and two other repos from another project to generate the necessary structure to build the docker image needed. The pipeline is failing at first step of checking-out the first repo from the other project with error:

```
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier my_repo_name does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'my_repo_name' not found
##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
```

This error is well documented in Azure DevOps docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#q--a

I was able to follow the instructions and correctly add the user current_project_name Build Service (org_name) (which existed before, I didn't create it) to my other project to both the repos with the necessary Create Tag, Read access but yet it keeps failing again.

A quick search on the internet related to the issue found others who were able to solve the problem with similar approaches, another user from developercommunity.visualstudio.com reported a bug relative to the repo name, which is reported fixed, but also not related to my naming scheme.

I would appreciate any hint on this.

System-diagnose-enabled logs:

```
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7026161Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Checkout my_repo_name@branch-name to s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7028997Z ##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7029712Z ##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7031453Z ##[debug]=> True
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7032579Z ##[debug]Result: True
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7033673Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout my_repo_name@branch-name to s/my_repo_name
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7039346Z ==============================================================================
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7039760Z Task         : Get sources
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7040166Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7040566Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7040823Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7041228Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-05-12T14:04:50.7041850Z ==============================================================================
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1060976Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[plugininternal.updaterepositorypath alias=my_repo_name;]/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1073510Z ##[debug]Repository requires to be placed at '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name', current location is '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1472643Z Syncing repository: my_repo_name (git)
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1493079Z ##[debug]repository url=https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1500653Z ##[debug]targetPath=/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1519093Z ##[debug]sourceBranch=refs/heads/branch-name
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1521059Z ##[debug]sourceVersion=9d9d1ddeb7ba058e4c1ead2cfc84fb6286169838
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1522993Z ##[debug]clean=False
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1524037Z ##[debug]checkoutSubmodules=False
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1525104Z ##[debug]checkoutNestedSubmodules=False
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1526598Z ##[debug]exposeCred=False
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1527760Z ##[debug]fetchDepth=0
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1528845Z ##[debug]gitLfsSupport=False
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1529873Z ##[debug]acceptUntrustedCerts=False
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1530779Z ##[debug]schannelSslBackend=False
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1589934Z ##[debug]Which: 'git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1653673Z ##[debug]Location: '{matches.First()}'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1672364Z ##[debug]Get git version.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1687205Z ##[command]git version
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1870323Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1871792Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1872922Z ##[debug]  Arguments: 'version'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1874014Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1875162Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1876939Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1879045Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1880531Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1881811Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1883039Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1883951Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1994315Z ##[debug]Exited process 2641 with exit code 0
2020-05-12T14:04:51.1998531Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2641, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2050490Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2189303Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2193841Z ##[debug]Finished process 2641 with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:00.0354826.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2195045Z git version 2.26.2
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2202161Z ##[debug]Detect git version: 2.26.2.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2203371Z ##[debug]Which: 'git-lfs'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2244957Z ##[debug]Location: '{matches.First()}'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2256697Z ##[debug]Get git-lfs version.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2258520Z ##[command]git lfs version
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2260402Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2262493Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2265496Z ##[debug]  Arguments: 'lfs version'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2268896Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2272008Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2274779Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2276598Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2279938Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2282047Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2283909Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2286017Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2301439Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2645.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2303866Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2645, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2385647Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2429252Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2431173Z ##[debug]Exited process 2645 with exit code 0
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2432607Z ##[debug]Finished process 2645 with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:00.0099436.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2434683Z git-lfs/2.10.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.4)
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2436118Z ##[debug]Detect git-lfs version: '2.10.0'.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2437198Z ##[debug]Set git useragent to: git/2.26.2 (vsts-agent-git/2.166.4).
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2441563Z ##[debug]Checking if the repo on /home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name matches the expected repository origin URL. expected Url: https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2444183Z ##[debug]Repository is not found since '.git' directory does not exist under. /home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2499145Z ##[debug]Init git repository at: /home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2510361Z ##[command]git init "/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name"
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2511293Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2512329Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2512986Z ##[debug]  Arguments: 'init "/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name"'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2513632Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2514575Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2516291Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2517923Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2519787Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2521504Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2523275Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2525052Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2548411Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2652.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2550126Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2652, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2584017Z Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name/.git/
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2589477Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2593576Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2615187Z ##[debug]Exited process 2652 with exit code 0
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2616059Z ##[debug]Finished process 2652 with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:00.0070099.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2617026Z ##[debug]Add git remote: origin to url: https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name for repository under: /home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2617937Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2618640Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2619507Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2620529Z ##[debug]  Arguments: 'remote add origin https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2621785Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2622679Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2623608Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2624492Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2625344Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2626267Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2627149Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2628339Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2640427Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2653.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2642220Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2653, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2663211Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2666696Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2684647Z ##[debug]Exited process 2653 with exit code 0
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2685549Z ##[debug]Finished process 2653 with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:00.0057216.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2687330Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setprogress value=0]Starting fetch...
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2688086Z ##[debug]Disable git auto garbage collection.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2688591Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2689179Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2690042Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2691478Z ##[debug]  Arguments: 'config gc.auto 0'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2693248Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2694493Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2695479Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2749342Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2750075Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2750654Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2751529Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2752129Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2752605Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2654.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2753117Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2654, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2753588Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2754013Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2754433Z ##[debug]Exited process 2654 with exit code 0
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2754987Z ##[debug]Finished process 2654 with exit code 0, and elapsed time 00:00:00.0061694.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2760670Z ##[debug]Checking git config http.https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name.extraheader exist or not
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2762334Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name.extraheader
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2763333Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2764099Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2765011Z ##[debug]  Arguments: 'config --get-all http.https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name.extraheader'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2765920Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2766686Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2767561Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2768342Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2769079Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2769786Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2770519Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2771260Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2785860Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2655.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2786477Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2655, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2801795Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2803249Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2814996Z ##[debug]Exited process 2655 with exit code 1
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2815856Z ##[debug]Finished process 2655 with exit code 1, and elapsed time 00:00:00.0050618.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2816621Z ##[debug]Checking git config http.proxy exist or not
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2817522Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2818209Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2819555Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2820261Z ##[debug]  Arguments: 'config --get-all http.proxy'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2821029Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2822476Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2823380Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2824053Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2824680Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2825273Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2825872Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2826462Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2827621Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2656.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2828701Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2656, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2837649Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2838475Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2908214Z ##[debug]Exited process 2656 with exit code 1
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2908854Z ##[debug]Finished process 2656 with exit code 1, and elapsed time 00:00:00.0027582.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2909327Z ##[debug]fetchDepth : 0
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2909701Z ##[debug]fetchByCommit : True
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2910131Z ##[debug]sourceVersion : 9d9d1ddeb7ba058e4c1ead2cfc84fb6286169838
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2911662Z ##[debug]Fetch git repository at: /home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name remote: origin.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2915696Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2916313Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2916896Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2919781Z ##[debug]  Arguments: '-c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2920691Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2921472Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2922056Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2922657Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2923197Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2923716Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2924267Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2924808Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2925648Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2657.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.2926164Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2657, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.4105389Z remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier my_repo_name does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.4109279Z fatal: repository 'https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name/' not found
2020-05-12T14:04:51.4125479Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.4126038Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.4126478Z ##[debug]Exited process 2657 with exit code 128
2020-05-12T14:04:51.4127039Z ##[debug]Finished process 2657 with exit code 128, and elapsed time 00:00:00.1216020.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.5179722Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=AzurePipelinesAgent;feature=GitFetch]{"ElapsedTimeMilliseconds":"124","RefSpec":"","RemoteName":"origin","FetchDepth":"0","ExitCode":"128","Options":"--force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin "}
2020-05-12T14:04:51.5219540Z ##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 3.818 seconds before retry.
2020-05-12T14:04:51.5231122Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 3.818 seconds before retry.
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2569105Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2570278Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2571534Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2574865Z ##[debug]  Arguments: '-c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2576010Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2576659Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2577258Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2577855Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2578410Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2578942Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2579494Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2580041Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2590335Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2671.
2020-05-12T14:04:55.2590881Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2671, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:55.3913623Z remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier my_repo_name does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
2020-05-12T14:04:55.3914981Z fatal: repository 'https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name/' not found
2020-05-12T14:04:55.3928226Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:55.3929729Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:55.3935126Z ##[debug]Exited process 2671 with exit code 128
2020-05-12T14:04:55.3935978Z ##[debug]Finished process 2671 with exit code 128, and elapsed time 00:00:00.1367994.
2020-05-12T14:04:55.4529967Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=AzurePipelinesAgent;feature=GitFetch]{"ElapsedTimeMilliseconds":"137","RefSpec":"","RemoteName":"origin","FetchDepth":"0","ExitCode":"128","Options":"--force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin "}
2020-05-12T14:04:55.4532940Z ##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 3.705 seconds before retry.
2020-05-12T14:04:55.4540363Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 3.705 seconds before retry.
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1017290Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1019284Z ##[debug]Starting process:
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1020257Z ##[debug]  File name: '/usr/bin/git'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1023516Z ##[debug]  Arguments: '-c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1024564Z ##[debug]  Working directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/my_repo_name'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1025344Z ##[debug]  Require exit code zero: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1026168Z ##[debug]  Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1026975Z ##[debug]  Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1027704Z ##[debug]  Redirected STDIN: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1028920Z ##[debug]  Persist current code page: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1029714Z ##[debug]  Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1030437Z ##[debug]  High priority process: 'False'
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1057658Z ##[debug]Updated oom_score_adj to 500 for PID: 2685.
2020-05-12T14:04:59.1060659Z ##[debug]Process started with process id 2685, waiting for process exit.
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2116975Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2136844Z remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier my_repo_name does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2138810Z ##[debug]Exited process 2685 with exit code 128
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2153175Z fatal: repository 'https://my_org.visualstudio.com/PROJECT_NAME/_git/my_repo_name/' not found
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2160119Z ##[debug]STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2162214Z ##[debug]Finished process 2685 with exit code 128, and elapsed time 00:00:00.1144540.
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2672809Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=AzurePipelinesAgent;feature=GitFetch]{"ElapsedTimeMilliseconds":"116","RefSpec":"","RemoteName":"origin","FetchDepth":"0","ExitCode":"128","Options":"--force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin "}
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2675019Z ##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2676698Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2686685Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2687848Z ##[debug]   at Agent.Plugins.Repository.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext executionContext, RepositoryResource repository, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Agent.Plugins.Repository.CheckoutTask.RunAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext executionContext, CancellationToken token)
   at Agent.PluginHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
2020-05-12T14:04:59.2692548Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout my_repo_name@branch-name to s/my_repo_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested with inline [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-declared-using-inline-syntax) : `- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization`, it can checked out multiple projects' repos normally. Can you share a sample of your yaml definition script ?

```
steps:
  - checkout: git://111/forTest
  - checkout: git://Test01/Test02
  - checkout: git://TestCsharp1/TestCsharp1
```

[image]

**Update**:

When I use this syntax: `- checkout: git://MY_OTHER_PROJECT/my_repo_name/repo_branch`, I can reproduce your problem:

[image]

To fix it ,we need to designate the ref by appending `@<ref>`. For example:

```
steps:
  - checkout: git://111/forTest@dev
```

Here is the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref) you can refer to .

Comment: Thanks for giving it a test. Here's my azure-pipelines.yml file: https://pastebin.com/XmknFzc2

Comment: Thanks for your sharing ,I can reproduce your problem, please view my update.

Comment: Hugh, appreciate your response however It didn't change the output. I even went ahead and removed the whole ref branch and kept the repos as `git://MY_OTHER_PROJECT/my_repo_name` and I'm still seeing the same error message.

Comment: Sorry for the late response . Is the job authorization scope of the pipeline "collection" or "project"? If the scope is collection,you need to check if `Project Collection Build Service (your-collection-name)` exists in the list of users in the repo security.

Comment: Hugh, it's "collection" and as I stated in the question I have added "current_project_name Build Service (org_name)" to "other_project" and gave it "Create tag, Read" access. Additionally I just confirmed again existence of "Project Collection Build Service (org_name)" and it does in both projects.